# Is there a way to get exact reporting time?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to get the exact reporting time, If a person clicks **"Yes"** then it will capture the exact time of that person. Everybody reporting at different times. So I want to capture their time without manual typing. Is there a way to approach it by using  Excel formula or VBA?

Thank you.

[image: Question]

Comment: Have you tied anything yet? Any VBA? You can get a timestamp using a formula or vba.

Comment: https://excelweez.com/how-to-timestamp-in-excel-when-cell-changes/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75634598/login-logout-is-not-calculating-instant
I tried this way in excel formula, but sometimes getting circular reference error

Comment: circular reference means.. the F5 cell's formula cannot use formula from 'F5' .. which is what u have now..

Comment: @braX Yeah got it & thanks a lot.. excelweez has given solution to my question.

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: A Drop-Down Time Stamp Combo

**Sheet Module, e.g. `Sheet1` (not `Module1` or `ThisWorkbook`)**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "B2"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "C"
    Const CRIT_STRING As String = "Yes"
    
    Dim srg As Range
    With Me.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
        Set srg = .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(srg, Target)
    
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim durg As Range, iCell As Range, dCell As Range
    
    For Each iCell In irg.Cells
        If StrComp(CStr(iCell.Value), CRIT_STRING, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set dCell = iCell.EntireRow.Columns(DST_COLUMN)
            If Len(CStr(dCell.Value)) = 0 Then
                If durg Is Nothing Then
                    Set durg = dCell
                Else
                    Set durg = Union(durg, dCell)
                End If
            'Else ' already filled do nothing
            End If
        'Else ' it's not the criteria string; do nothing
        End If
    Next iCell
    
    If durg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        durg.Value = Now
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```